# set form parts invisible

Tags: javascript, html

I have one form with input fields. After the first part there are 2 buttons (external, internal) the external redirects you somewhere else the internal button should show (set visible) more input fields.

like

```
<form action="servlet_link" method="post">
<table class="ui-widget">
    <colgroup width="350" span="2"></colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p class="form">
                Familyname
            </p><td>
            <input class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all" name="familyname" type="text"">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p class="form">
                Givenname
            </p></td>
            <td>
            <input class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all" name="ustid" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    <div class="center">
    <!-- Buttons -->
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- sends data post and redirects u -->
                <a href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit()" class="btn" name="extern">External</a>                                  
            </td>
            <td>
                <!-- shows more input fields and sets both buttons invisible --> 
                <a href="???" class="btn" name="intern" >Internal</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

    <!-- part 2 should be shown -->

    <table class="ui-widget">
    <colgroup width="350" span="2"></colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p class="form">
                Companyname
            </p><td>
            <input class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all" name="companyname" type="text"">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p class="form">
                address
            </p></td>
            <td>
            <input class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all" name="address" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    <div class="center">
    <!-- Buttons -->
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- sends data post and redirects u -->
                <a href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit()" class="btn" name="extern">External</a>                                  
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Do i have to give all elements a id tag and set it invisible through:

JS:

```
function invisbleForm() {

            document.getElementById("companynameText").style.display ="block";

    }
```

Is there better solution to do that ?
thx for any help :)

**UPDATE 1**

Ok to set it visible and invisible is not the problem put i have a big white block on my page how can i dynamically resize it?

Comment: You need to familiarize yourself with the concept of CSS "classes". Elements that have the same behavior can be controlled by a common set of CSS rules.

Comment: you could go to jquery.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could do this:

Assing an id to your form then add a class 'myFields' to the input fields you wish to show.
Then try this:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('FormId');
var ipnutFieldsToShow = myForm.getElementsByClassName('myFields');
for(var i = 0; i < inputFieldsToShow.length; i++) {
   inputFieldsToShow[i].style.display ="block";
}
```

Comment: thanks works perfectly fine with `display: none;` and `display: block;`

Comment: No prob, take care :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class name to each element you want to show and the use the native method "document.getElementsByClassName".

Take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName